# Indent for username

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, user-accounts

In [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4421/176217) OP [user name](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/199182) has strange indent even when hats are disabled for the app:

> [image: app post]

Same for the profile page in the app:

> [image: profile app]

Web shows user name without indent (no matter hats are enabled or not):

> [image: web]

Seems the user name contains some unprintable character(s), which are ignored in web, but not in the app. Sorting by name in the app shows this user in the beginning (almost) of the list:

> [image: user list]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the design is "fixed" as long as winterbash is active, even if you disable hats. If it will still be an issue after winterbash is over, it's a bug indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard even if it is only for winter bash seasons - it is a bug.

Comment: It's that user's name in particular, there's extra space *everywhere* that username is shown

Comment: @Cai true. Even in comments. Didn't see before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in most places in 1.6.3.3.

This user has 5 spaces at the start of their display name.  When the user's name is displayed on the web, the browser collapses the multiple spaces into a single one.  iOS's UILabel does not.  I'm updating the code that adds diamonds to moderators to also strip off leading and trailing spaces, as well as multiple adjacent spaces inside names.  That should catch most cases where user names are displayed.